# Using COPY command with subquery in PL\pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

there is an example of function i'm trying to create:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exchange_to_csv()
  RETURNS integer AS $$
    DECLARE
    xseq integer;
    BEGIN
      SELECT max(events_stage.seq) FROM events_stage INTO xseq;
      IF xseq is not NULL THEN
        EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * from events_stage WHERE events_stage.seq <= $1) TO ''/tmp/test.csv'' WITH CSV' USING xseq;
        DELETE FROM event_stage WHERE event_stage.seq <= xseq;
      END IF;
      RETURN xseq;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Executing this code i get the following error:

```
[42P02] ERROR: there is no parameter $1
```

As i understand $1 isn't exist inside subquery. Is there a way, how i can pass this param there?

Answer (score 0):

`$1` is the first parameter in your function. Your function `exchange_to_csv()` has not parameters so `$1` is not recognized.

If you want to pass a parameter you need to change your function to:

```
exchange_to_csv(x Type)
```

Type can be `Integer`, `Text` etc...
Then from function body you can access `x` by its name `x` or by `$1`